# Docker Nginx Nodejs load balancing

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have recently started to be interested in Docker and Nginx. I would like to set up load balancing but I don't know how to go about it. Can anyone tell me what I should do.
I read a bit about upstream, but I don't really understand how to configure this part and connect it to the nginx configuration.

```
====docker-compose.yml=====
version: "3.7"
  # expose:
  #   - 8080
  # ports:
  #   - 8080:8080

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - nginx-network
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    command: npm run dev
    environment:
      - dbURI=mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017
    networks:
      - app-network
      - nginx-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
  nginx-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

```
=====Dockerfile=====
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

```
====default.conf nginx=====
default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name test.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please divide the code into seperate pieces, that makes readability easier. Also, the question is quite broad. First have a look into Nginx documentation on load balancing. Then check into DNS names in the docker (compose) network. These steps together should make it relatively easy to do this.

Comment: I will try to do this.